# TeXstudio: Disable spell check in non-text environment

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I am using TeXstudio 2.6.6 on Ubuntu and I am having a problem with the spell checker. It keeps checking non-text environments, e.g. math environments, so I get spelling errors for indices, variables etc. which is rather inconvenient. Same problem occurs for instance with \label{...} or \cite{...}.

In the settings, I ticked the boxes for hiding spelling and grammar errors in non-text environments with the effect that the "errors" are not underlined in the editor. However, they still show up as errors when I run the spell check.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Cheers,
Judith

Comment: 2.6.6 is way outdated. The current version is 2.12.2 and detection of text and non-text commands is significantly improved. I suggest to upgrade.

Comment: So far I wasn't able to install TeXstudio 2.12.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. Installing the rpm package from the TeXstudio website gave me a bunch of errors. I installed version 2.9.4 via ppa but here those unwanted spelling errors still occur. Any suggestions on what the best way of upgrading on Ubuntu 14.04 is?